# Side effects of defining a structure inside a class

Tags: vb.net, class, structure, side-effects

A newbie vb.net question

What is the side effects of defining a structure inside a class (name it X), and create a property inside that class of the type X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no side-effects.

The only *effect* is that the structure is within the scope of the class, that is, if you want to use the scope from outside the class it has to be declared as `Public` and you nee to qualify the name explicitly as `OuterClassName.InnerStructureName` when using it.

Notably (and unlike in Java), the structure is not related to any *instance* of the class it’s contained in. So it cannot just access its surrounding class’s instance members.